# Sqlite query not returning data in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite-net

I am using Sqlite with C#. When i run the query in Sqlite browser it returns the correct data but when i run the same query from C# code it does not return data. My C# code is:

```
foreach (var group in groups)
{
        var edgeDataWithGroupCmd = EdgeDatabase._connection.CreateCommand(@"SELECT ad.Id, ad.Name, adType.Id, adType.Name, h.Data, chart.URL
                                                                                    from
                                                                                    tblAdapter ad JOIN
                                                                                    tblAdapterType adType ON ad.AdapterTypeId = adType.Id JOIN 
                                                                                    tblHealth h ON ad.HealthId = h.Id JOIN 
                                                                                    tblCharts chart ON ad.ChartId = chart.Id 
                                                                                    WHERE ad.GroupId = " + group.Id);



        List<EdgeData> edgeDatas = edgeDataWithGroupCmd.ExecuteQuery<EdgeData>();
}
```

When i run this query in C#, query does return a list of "EdgeData" but all the values are set to there default and not the exact data from database. I am using sqlite-net.

EdgeData is a custom class:

```
public class EdgeData
{
    public int AdapterId { get; set; }
    public string AdapterName { get; set; }
    public int AdapterTypeId { get; set; }
    public string AdapterTypeName { get; set; }
    public bool IsConnected { get; set; }
    public int MaxRefreshRate { get; set; }
    public int AchievedRefreshRate { get; set; }
    public string ChartLink { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the definition of `EdgeData`, and `Query<T>`, is that from Dapper? Also, there is no need for the command here, you only pass the SQL as a string to that Query method, you're not using the command object, so you can just do `string sql = @"SELECT ...";`

Comment: Code has been updated a bit, can you kindly check now. EdgeData definition is also provided @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: Since the property names in the `EdgeData` type and the field names returned from the query do not match, Dapper or whichever library you're using that provide `Query` doesn't map correctly between the two. Try `SELECT ad.Id AS AdapterId, ...`, or add attributes or whatnot that would tell the library how to map correctly.

Comment: Specifically, the field you're returning with the query is `Id`, yet the property name is `AdapterId`, either these two have to match, or you need to tell the mapping implementation how to map between the two.

Comment: It worked :) Thanks brother, u made my day :) @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Answer (score 0):

```
    //get one instance, and use function in logic/business layer to create list
    //or rebuild function to return a list<EdgeData>
    public EdgeData GetEdgeData(int groupID)
    {
        connection.open();

        EdgeData edgeData;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("SELECT ad.Id, ad.Name, adType.Id, adType.Name, h.Data, chart.URL
                    from
                    tblAdapter ad JOIN
                    tblAdapterType adType ON ad.AdapterTypeId = adType.Id JOIN 
                    tblHealth h ON ad.HealthId = h.Id JOIN 
                    tblCharts chart ON ad.ChartId = chart.Id 
                    WHERE ad.GroupId = @GroupId");


        SqlDataReader data;
        String sql = sb.ToString();
        //Use sql injection instead of "+"
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupId", groupID);
            data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }

        while (data.Read())
        {
             int AdapterId = (int)data["ad.Id"]
             string AdapterName = (string)data["ad.Name"]
             int AdapterTypeId = ...
             string AdapterTypeName = ...
             bool IsConnected = ...
             int MaxRefreshRate = ...
             int AchievedRefreshRate = ..
             string ChartLink = ..


             edgeData = new EdgeData(AdapterId, AdapterName, etc...);
        }

        connection.Close();
        return edgeData;
    }
```

Comment: I am using Sqlite-net @Jesse Van Evert. Your code will not work there.